# How can I mark the seams to UV unwrap a torus?

Tags: texturing, uv

So, uh... I've been using blender for a couple months, and I'm still lost on how the heck texturing works. I would like unwrap this torus, the problem is, it has way too many vertices to for me to even try and mark seams.

[image]

I want to unwrap it properly, to where it doesn't appear like... this:
[image]

Texturing is the most difficult part for me.. I just recently learned (somewhat) proper rigging. I still have not been able to figure out textures though... I am only able to add them on simple things like that clock on the cylinder.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to unwrap a torus (or any mesh). A lot of it depends on your needs and the kind of projection you are after.

One way is to mark one seam that splits the torus horizontally and one that does it vertically:

[image]

Then select one of the faces where the seams meet

[image]

and press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect and <kbd>A</kbd> again to select all faces. That way you will have all of the faces selected but will also have an active face.

Press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap and select **follow active quads**

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

Form there on you can scale, assign a texture, etc.

[image]