# How do I rotate to animate, a torus around its minor axis?

Tags: animation, uv

I am trying to map an image of an arrow around a torus and then rotate the torus to animate it, around both its major axis and its minor axis.

Either I can rotate the mapped image, or I can rotate the torus?
Can I create an array of a cylinder and map the image of the arrow onto the array?

I have tried using armatures in the torus and rotating the armatures both around the minor axis and the major axis of the the torus but this kinks the surface of the torus.

The single arrow, on a grid 24x24, extends to the full extent of the torus' surface, which is divided into 24x24 faces to facilitate mapping - whether in Blender or not, but in 2D animation.

Ultimately two torri are linked, each with its own arrow image, one positive and the other negative.

Here is a link to the entire completed animation done in 2D:
[enter link description here](https://www.sites.google.com/site/hesusjoychrist/home/hesus-joy-christ/the-spirit-of-one-animated)

Here is a .gif of the completed animation done in 2D.
I would like to be able to duplicate this 2D animation in 3D Blender.
[image]

Here are some more images to illustrate the mapping:
[image: Male positive Arrow image mapping]
[image: Female negative Arrow image mapping]
Here is a 2D map of the arrows, ***but I am using 12x12 rather than 10x10, and the arrows are full bleed in that they both extend each to the limit of the torrus mappings***[image]

https://sites.google.com/site/vid932008/animation/blender#TOC-3D-Computer-Animation-is-unable-to-resolve-the-rotation-of-the-Spirit-of-One

Comment: Is the link what you are trying to make? Because I sure did not get that from your question. You might want to edit it and try to make it more clear what you want to model.

Comment: Ideally all information to understand the question should be contained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to animate a texture.

Here an arrow is mapped on top of the material of the torus. Animating the coordinates for the texture makes the arrow move around the surface:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What sorcery did you use to unwrap the torus cleanly and undistorted?

Comment: @Haunt_House just one vertical seam, select a quad right next to the seam, select all (so that all are selected but one is active). Unwrap using follow active quads...

Comment: @Haunt_House also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96198/how-can-i-mark-the-seams-to-uv-unwrap-a-torus

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to animate an arrow going round a torus, this is one way of how I would do it:

Model your arrow, then shear the arrow and warp it to make it coil.

[image]

Create a lattice and make sure the arrow fits inside. I used ten divisions, less might still be ok. Give the arrow a lattice deform. Parent the arrow to the lattice.

Then use warp again, this time on the lattice. It makes sure the arrow bends around the torus.

[image]

Now you just have to animate the lattice in a circle and animate the arrow with local rotation. The lattice will deform the arrow while it rotates.

[image]

Here's the finished result:

[image]

If you want a snug fit, use a shrinkwrap modifier on top with just a smidge of offset. It might even make the lattice unnecessary.

[image]

Of course there's more than one way of doing this. If you want to turn the torus in itself, here's how:

Create a torus and an armature. Doesn't have to be low poly, it's just a bit easier. Put the cursor in the middle of the top edgeloop.

[image]

Move the bone in Edit mode to the cursor. Then put the cursor in the middle and duplicate the bone. You can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to do t quickly.

[image]

Create a ninth bone and give all other bones Copy Rotation Constraints to that bone, local coordinates to local coordinates. Parent the torus to the armature using envelopes. You can also use weight paint or any other method, just make sure that every bone has only one edgeloop under his control. No kinks whatsoever.

[image]

Finishing touches. I moved the ninth bone to the center, gave all of them a custom shape and rotated the ninth bone so that it's relevant axis points towards the screen. When I rotate the main bone clockwise, all others rotate inwards.

[image]

And the finished result:

[image]

Comment: I really like both answers !!!

Comment: It will be a challenge for me to achieve either or both of these methods with my limited Blender experience but your answers make sense to me and inspire me.

Comment: Can't get it to work. First the torus flips around, than I cannot get the envelopes to influence the torus to make it rotate around the minor axis. I thought I had it rotating around the minor axis but then again, maybe I never did get that to work.   . . . .. . .. .  . . . .. .... .. .. .. . .    .. .. . ... . .

Comment: There's a difference between "I can't get it to work" and " I haven't done it yet". Try to get the armature to work with all the copy rot constraints. Ignore the torus until they do what they're supposed to do. Switch on axes so you see whether they all point in the same way. And I am still pretty peeved about what you wrote on your website about what Blender cannot do.

Comment: I apologize for that statement that Blender "cannot" and I admit that you have been able to get it to do exactly what I am trying to get it to do.

Comment: I realize that Blender is so versatile that it is complex, and that makes it unwieldy to a novice  like myself.  I mastered Autocadd singlehandedly in 1991, including autolisp, so I am aware that there is still a lot to Blender for me to at least become aware of what every little setting does.  I plan to keep trying before I return to seasonal employment, and run out of time this winter.

Comment: I noticed that changing one of the two settings from Local to World in the Copy Rot Constraint seems to make a difference, but I know you said they should be both set to Local, so I am watching to see what else may have messed it up.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience and your reply, in the midst of my frustration. Your reply means that my time spent figuring this out is justified, and I was beginning to question that assumption of mine. I will work on it the next chance I get, and again and again. Autocad was the same but far easier being less versatile. Thank You!!!

Comment: I will check axis orientations like you said, and double check all the constraints.   Should I be parenting at all? . . . . and should I look for a setting to apply envelopes?   .. . . . and should check rotations such as xyz Euler or Quaternion?     Thank you very much for your patience.  I will change the statement on the website with a sincere apology when I get this to work like you have so clearly shown me that it is possible.  Thank You !!!

Comment: To date I have about two months of work put into this, mostly in 2014, but that still does not justify my statement.  Back then I made 24 armatures around the major axis of the torus that rotated the torus' minor axis with envelopes as they all rotated around the major axis, and I knife cut the torus and gave it a translucent surface and lighting.  I got that far and then it kinked as you saw on the website.     Thank you !!!

Comment: local and world are crucial. local copies the , for example, x rotation to the x rotation of all the bones. that way I can place them in a circle and all of them use their own axis, hence the circular rotation

Comment: @RDavidFoster download this one. It might help: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49014

Comment: I do not have the time to ferret out settings and orientations and constraints and parenting to get this to work. I have been shown above that it is possible, so I believe it is, but I do not have the time to get to know blender well enough to be able to achieve the rotating torus arrows that I need. If anyone can do what I have attempted I will pay them upon completion. Otherwise I need more than just "Shift-R-", as that does nothing on the blender that I have installed. It took me six months of 70 hour weeks to get up to speed on Autocad 11 in 1991 and I simply do not have that kind of time.