# how to draw a torus with grid?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I want to model a torus with grid, i.e torus code in topology quantum computation, just like followin, but I do not know how to draw grid.

Maybe using texture might be helpful, but are there any other ways?

[image: torus code]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/rendering-with-wireframe

Comment: thanks, this solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a wireframe node or modifier. You may be able to duplicate the torus and then apply the wireframe to the outer torus if you want it to look more 3D. But you can also try the wireframe node.

Comment: thanks very much, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap the UVs for the torus

See:
[How can I mark the seams to UV unwrap a torus?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96198/how-can-i-mark-the-seams-to-uv-unwrap-a-torus)

Then use the UV mapping on a brick texture with no offset, and a frequency of 1. The fac output you can use to control a color mix used as color on the material.

[image]

Or you can **Export the UV layout**.

[image]

You'll get an image like this saved on a file, where each of the vertices on the mesh is represented by a line and the faces are the alpha channel:

[image]

Then use that image to control the mix of whatever colors you want.

[image]

(the color ramp is there to make the alpha channel more contrasted, only pure black and pure white)

Comment: thanks, this seems a nice way