# Why my texture painting is repeating?

Tags: texturing

I was following the doughnut tutorial made by Blender Guru,and I bumped into some problem:

1.I can't get the purple doughnut in UV editing mode. (So I UV unwrapped,did get a purple doughnut in Texture paint mode(not in UV editing mode),but don't know what would that help or effect anything)
[image]
(After UV unwrap)
[image]
(Got a purple doughnut in Texture paint mode)

2.And then I pressed the **+ New** on top of the left panel to add a new image(2048*1042),and used Shading node to add the image to the texture of the doughnut,then I started painting,found out that my texture is repeating.
[image]
(Add the texture to the doughnut)
[image]
(The texture repeating)

Sorry for the bad English.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is repeating either because you've unwrapped every quad to the whole UV coordinate space (each quad becomes a square going from x:0,y:0 to x:1, y:1), or because of this setting on your *Image Texture* node:

[image]

What this *"Repeat"* means is that if a particular point of a mesh is mapped (in the UV map) to a point (texel) outside the texture (e.g. x: `-5`), then it should be *"wrapped"* from the other side, so for an image 2048 pixels long, the x: `-5` becomes x: `2048-5` = x: `2043`. This repeats, so x: `-6000` becomes x: `2048-5000` = x: `-2952`, which becomes x: `2048-2952`, which becomes x: `2048-904` = x: `1144`. The effect is that a mesh with UV map spanning from x: `-6144` to x: `2048` will repeat (horizontally) 4 times.

Go to the **UV Editing** tab, edit your mesh, select all faces (<kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>) and on the left side see if some of the quads go outside the texture - if so, select everything there (again <kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>) and scale it down (<kbd>S</kbd>) until it fits. If you only see a single quad, then you need to properly unwrap the mesh.

[How can I mark the seams to UV unwrap a torus?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/96198/)